# Empty file list when dropping a file on the input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop

I have created a file input looking like an empty rectangle with an `onDrop` event attached to it. I'm trying to catch a dropped file and send it over ajax request. The problem is that I can't get the file inside an event:

```
$(this).val() // empty
this.refs.file.files // empty
this.refs.file.value // empty
event.dataTransfer.files // empty
```

It works as a normal input, but here it's all empty. What's wrong?

```
<input type="file" ref="file" className="dropzone_file" onDrop={(e) => this.dropFile(e)} />
```

Comment: Include dropFile function.